# Outgoing links in civimail getting changed to civi site address

Tags: civimail

I setup a mailing in civi and in the email there are links to web pages not on the civi site. When I send the test message the link is changed to the civi site and not the actual link.

example 
good link

http://www.google.com

link that shows up

http://civi.mysite.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you set your mailing to track clicks on links, it automatically replaces every link with an auto-generated CiviCRM url - this will redirect to the original link, but has to go through CiviCRM to be tracked.

If you haven't chosen to track clicks, or if the CiviCRM url just goes to your site without redirecting, then there's a problem, but otherwise it's intentional.

Comment: Okay. I thought the track replies caused it. Thanks